# What does "be drawn before someone" mean?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, phrasal-verbs

In Oxford learner's dictionary, the word "drag", in one sense, means:

> a strong-smelling lure drawn before hounds as a substitute for a fox or other hunted animal.

My understand is that "be drawn to" means "be attracted to", for example:

> Her eyes were immediately drawn to the tall blond man standing at the bar.

means that the woman is being attracted by the tall blond man.

With that, "be drawn before" shouldn't have the same meaning as "be drawn to".

So what is the meaning of "be drawn before" in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must understand ***draw*** *in the **literal** sense of **pulling***:

> to pull or direct something in a particular direction:
>
> - draw the curtains ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draw))

The hounds are hunting dogs that normally track or chase prey. But in order to protect wildlife, hunters replace the actual prey with something which smells like prey (like a fox in this case) and they *drag* or *draw* it (literal sense) ***before*** (i.e. ***in front of***) the hounds so that they run after it just as in real hunting. It's called ***drag hunting***:

> For those who think that some sort of ‘hunting’ should continue because it’s a grand old British tradition – it can. ***Drag hunting*** and bloodhounds hunting (known as ‘clean boot’), in which the hunt follows an artificial trail and not a live animal, involve many of the elements of the ‘sport’, but without killing wildlife.
>
> ***Drag hunting*** (not to be confused with trail hunting) can provide an alternative to the use of a pack of foxhounds in the countryside while minimising the risk to wildlife. It was created in the 1800s.
> [league.org.uk](https://www.league.org.uk/media/filer_public/d4/2e/d42ed760-6dca-4f8a-9797-da413fa96b96/drag_hunting_clean_boot_hunting_and_trail_hunting.pdf)

Edit: In response to your comment, here is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_hunting) says about *drag hunting*:

> The primary difference between fox hunting and drag hunting is the hounds are trained to hunt a prepared scent trail *laid by a person **dragging** a material soaked in aniseed or another strong smelling substance*.

It looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: And the woman's eyes are being metaphorically 'pulled' towards the attractive man.

Comment: @fev, I've found those 2 articles:- https://www.immaterieelerfgoed.nl/en/slipjacht#:~:text=History,an%20artificially%20drawn%20fox%20track.
- https://www.huntingact.org/hunting/hunting-terms/. Based on that, do you think "draw" (the active form of "drawn") could mean "to produce by marks" (and "marks" here is the artificial scent track) rather than "to pull"?
Also, I couldn't imagine how this artificial fox track can be "pulled" before hounds.

Comment: @KhanhTran No, it does not mean "to produce by marks". It simply means dragging the rope with a piece of material that has that smell.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that ‘before’ in the quote means ‘in front of’ — a meaning of ‘before’ which was historically quite widely used but is now fairly rare, mostly only in a few fossilised phrases like ‘pearls before swine’.

Comment: @PLL I would think, "She appeared before my eyes" is literary, but still quite common...

Comment: @fev: completely agreed — there are a good few phrases and contexts where it’s still used, especially in literary language as you say.  I just wanted to point out (since it sounds like OP is a second-language speaker) that this sense of *before* is good to know and recognise, but that learners shouldn’t think of it as a general-purpose synonym of *in front of*.

Comment: @PLL The point you are making is spot on. I hadn't picked up on the fact that _before_ can be misleading because of its temporal meaning as well...

Comment: As in the schoolboy joke, "How dare you f*rt before my wife?" "I'm sorry, I didn't know it was her turn."